# Can't access HTTP contents, but HTTPS and SSH are fine

Tags: networking, ip, internet

I'm having a weired issue wih my Fedora 14 recently. Many details involed. Let's start from this:

I've been using Fedora 14 for months, and recent few days, offten I can't access Internet for hours. I can verify by a iPod Touch that connected to the same router, that the connection is fine.

Say the `traceroute` below. Any tips?

**-- updates --**

The computer has two network devices, eth0 and wlan0.

When having the problem in Linux, I can't access Internet from neither. But if booted into Windows 7 on the same machine and the same time, Internet is available via wlan0, but not eth0!

It sounds like that eth0 is broken? But I can use SSH and HTTPS via eth0 under Linux.

Now it's fine again. But I suspect it will happens again in few days. I'll post the tcpTraceroute then.

**traceroute on Linux**

```
traceroute to 163.com (220.181.8.178), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  58.246.230.1 (58.246.230.1)  6.228 ms * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * 112.64.243.170 (112.64.243.170)  6.627 ms
 7  * * *
 8  219.158.15.141 (219.158.15.141)  7.874 ms * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * 202.97.53.21 (202.97.53.21)  57.812 ms
13  * * *
14  220.181.16.138 (220.181.16.138)  57.633 ms * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * 220.181.8.178 (220.181.8.178)  59.643 ms
```

**traceroute on Router (Tomato)**

```
traceroute to 163.com (220.181.8.90), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  58.246.230.1 (58.246.230.1)  2.178 ms  2.125 ms  9.450 ms
 2  112.64.245.49 (112.64.245.49)  1.491 ms  1.361 ms  1.104 ms
 3  112.64.245.37 (112.64.245.37)  1.647 ms  1.351 ms  1.712 ms
 4  112.64.247.1 (112.64.247.1)  1.911 ms  4.424 ms  2.837 ms
 5  112.64.243.170 (112.64.243.170)  2.322 ms  2.242 ms  2.126 ms
 6  112.64.243.89 (112.64.243.89)  2.903 ms  2.345 ms  2.032 ms
 7  219.158.21.237 (219.158.21.237)  3.180 ms  2.553 ms  2.501 ms
 8  219.158.96.49 (219.158.96.49)  25.018 ms  24.734 ms  24.605 ms
 9  219.158.5.82 (219.158.5.82)  24.555 ms  24.450 ms  24.473 ms
10  219.158.35.2 (219.158.35.2)  53.599 ms  77.827 ms  53.791 ms
11  202.97.53.21 (202.97.53.21)  55.111 ms  54.861 ms  55.390 ms
12  220.181.16.2 (220.181.16.2)  55.531 ms  56.193 ms  55.430 ms
13  220.181.16.138 (220.181.16.138)  52.883 ms  56.370 ms  54.770 ms
14  220.181.17.58 (220.181.17.58)  61.931 ms  51.274 ms  53.879 ms
15  220.181.8.90 (220.181.8.90)  50.331 ms  50.219 ms  50.177 ms
```

Comment: Are you using wireless? Do you have the same problem if you connect to your router with an ethernet cable?

Comment: When you are behind the great firewall of China, anything is possible... could you go to `https://bitbucket.org/mpenning/template/src` and install `scapy/tcpTraceroute.py` in your home directory?  You will also need to have [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapy-latest.tar.gz) installed.  Then edit your question with the results of `python tcpTraceroute.py 163.com 80` and `python tcpTraceroute.py 163.com 443` (as root).  I may be able to help after you do this...

Comment: Can you paste the output of `ethtool eth0` and `ifconfig eth0`?

Comment: @Cheng, tcpdump is not likely very helpful yet... we need to understand the exact path your http traffic takes and if that is different than https; the only way to find this information is with tcptraceroute.  If there are any firewalls, caches, proxies or load-balancers then tcptraceroute will help highlight this.  I wrote my python version to be more helpful than the standard tcptraceroute.

Comment: A TCP trace wont help. Traffic doesnt take a different path based on the type of content. Routers operate on layer 3. TCP is layer 4.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I was not familiar with those concepts. But you made me much clear. Yep, I mean tcptraceroute.

Comment: @Patrick, routers were the only thing in the internet 20 years ago.  You should think about how the internet is built today... proxies, cache, load-balancers, etc. also, how does akamai cache content for Cisco.com.

Comment: Really need to see the routing setup. Sounds like you plugged 2 interfaces into the same network using the same netmask and not bridging them or using some kind of link aggregation, so the router just round robins the packets.

Comment: @mike proxies will kill your tcptraceroute as your tcp session ends at the proxy. cache, ditto. load-balancers wont even show up on a tcp trace. Next?

Comment: @patrick, So maybe that is the point, next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restored router with it's original firmware instead of Tomato. Although I've been using Tomato for several months without any problem, but it seems that the problem is gone now.

Comment: [谢谢你解释你对我们的解决方案。](http://translate.google.com/#zh-CN|en|%E8%B0%A2%E8%B0%A2%E4%BD%A0%E8%A7%A3%E9%87%8A%E4%BD%A0%E5%AF%B9%E6%88%91%E4%BB%AC%E7%9A%84%E8%A7%A3%E5%86%B3%E6%96%B9%E6%A1%88%E3%80%82)